# How to attach java docs to jar in osgi plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I'm trying to attach the java docs in my eclipse IDE and I am a little bit confused.

I've seen an answer where I had to click on project> properties> JavaDoc location> then insert java doc/api.
[image]
Yet another said I had to click on Window> prefernce> Installed Jre>edit> select /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar.> attach java doc/api. I did that for all the jar files[image]

In both cases, it doesn't seem to work. I still see the not attached java doc message for package`javax.jms`. I'd like to have the doc for all the classes I have in my eclipse project. It is an osgi project so I'd like to do it for the whole project and not for individual plugins.

****UPDATE****

- Also tried using maven eclipse integration i.e install plugin> click on download artifact source and javaDoc. Didn't work.
- It looks like it has to do with the plugin dependencies. When I attach the java doc to the jar in the plugin dependency and restart eclipse there's no javadoc attached. I guess there's another way of doing so with jars found in Plug-in dependencies.
  Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: How are you managing the dependencies? Are you using Ant or Maven?

Comment: The maven plugin wasn't installed yet because I have some issues with it. I think I'm using ant. Anyways I don't know how to tell.

Comment: Here is the manual process - if you looking to attach source/javadoc on only a couple of jars.  
  
To attach the source file to the Jar, there are different mechanism depending on how your doing dependency management. The manual way would be Right Click on Project --> Properties --> Libraries --> Drill to Jar in Question --> Source Attachment and add the source files folder/jar

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried that already.